# Status bar always on screen

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Good day (or evening, or night)
I'm developing an app for android and I'm very curious about one thing. I have an activity, where user chats with another, like "im" chat. There are an EditText on the bottom and some kind of actionbar on the top. What I need is when user enters a message and the software keyboard is on screen, my activity should move up, but the actionbar should still be "glued" to the top of the screen, because it has some valuable controls on it.
Again, that's not an ActionBar, but just a 48dp height layout in a parent vertical linear layout. So I need to know is there an easy way to prevent it from moving to the top, when the layout moves off the screen.
I tried to put everything in a FrameLayout and put this bar on top of it, but on keyboard opens it goes off the screen too...

Answer (score 0):

On you Activity at AndroidManifest you should put this: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.myapp.MyActionBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mylayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1dp"/>

    <!-- Add your edittext and button -->

</LinearLayout>
```

This will make sure the actionbar and edittext + button are allways on screen, and the `mylayout` takes up the rest of the screen. When your keyboard is shown, the `mylayout` will shrink.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" to your activity in the manifest.  This tells Android to completely resize your layout when the keyboard comes up, rather than pan it.  Note that if there isn't enough room for the entire layout this still won't work.  But you ought to be able to make it work if your top level layout is a RelativeLayout, with the edit text set to align bottom, the top bar to align top, and the middle section to fill_parent and be above the edit text and below the bar.

Answer (score 0):

use a RelativeLayout as your base Layout and add android:layout_alignParentTop="true" to your action bar to keep it up

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```